# Prioritizing specific endpoints on Heroku to skip / spend less time in request queue

Tags: heroku, request-queueing

Our API service has several endpoints and one of them is critical for the user experience because it directly affects the page load time.

Is there a way to priotize calls to `GET /api/priority_endpoint` over `GET /api/regular_endpoint` so the prioritized requests spend less time in the requests queue?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. All requests are sent to a random dyno as soon as they're within the router.
The only way you could do this would be by writing your own request queue in your app's code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Is this feature anywhere in your roadmap? :)

Comment: No. Nor would it be a good idea. It would make performance analysis much harder to do, and break the HTTP standard.